# how to add buttons to the default maps project in android studio?

Tags: java, android, xml, google-maps, android-fragments

i've opned the default "google maps activity" , activity in android studio just to learn some stuff for myself, the thing is it opnes a fragment XML on full screen and puts a map view in all of it, 
i want to add buttons, meaning adding another fragment or another xml layout of some sort, how can i do this ?
also what do i need to change in the Java file to call the new map \ buttons. ?

thnx !

this is the main code for the app >

```
package greenroadproject.greenroadproject2;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    /**
     * Sets up the map if it is possible to do so (i.e., the Google Play services APK is correctly
     * installed) and the map has not already been instantiated.. This will ensure that we only ever
     * call {@link #setUpMap()} once when {@link #mMap} is not null.
     * <p/>
     * If it isn't installed {@link SupportMapFragment} (and
     * {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView MapView}) will show a prompt for the user to
     * install/update the Google Play services APK on their device.
     * <p/>
     * A user can return to this FragmentActivity after following the prompt and correctly
     * installing/updating/enabling the Google Play services. Since the FragmentActivity may not
     * have been completely destroyed during this process (it is likely that it would only be
     * stopped or paused), {@link #onCreate(Bundle)} may not be called again so we should call this
     * method in {@link #onResume()} to guarantee that it will be called.
     */
    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case, we
     * just add a marker near Africa.
     * <p/>
     * This should only be called once and when we are sure that {@link #mMap} is not null.
     */
    private void setUpMap() {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
    }
}
```

and it uses this xml layout >

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity" />
```

this can also be found if you just open the normal google maps activity in android studio it's the same code.

so how do i add buttons to all of this \ make the map a bit smaller ?

thnx allot

sv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take `LinearLayout` as parent put map fragment as well as button on parent `LinearLayout`.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:context=".MapsActivity" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thank you , and what do i need to change in the main java file ? \ how do i adress the button in the linear layout ?

Answer (score 1):

In your xml file use below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00BCD4"
    android:id="@+id/main">

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp" android:id="@+id/map"
        tools:context=".MapsActivity"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:background="#536DFE"
        android:id="@+id/buttonMaps"
    />
```

In your onCreate method in MapsActivity.java use below codes to address your button.

```
    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonMaps);
```

To add actions when your buttonMaps is clicked, add below code.

```
buttonMaps.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

        //Add your code to be executed when button is clicked

        }
});
```